# Iterating over a hash response and saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

I have a hash response that looks like this.

```
{
    "count": 1,
    "filters": {
        "status": [
            "FINISHED"
        ]
    },
    "competition": {
        "id": 2015,
        "name": "Ligue 1",
    },
    "matches": [
        {
            "id": 296861,
            "score": {
                "winner": "HOME_TEAM",
                "fullTime": {
                    "homeTeam": 4,
                    "awayTeam": 1
                },
            "homeTeam": {
                "id": 523,
                "name": "Olympique Lyonnais"
            },
            "awayTeam": {
                "id": 528,
                "name": "Dijon Football Côte d'Or"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I will like to iterate over it and save selected values to the associated model.
At the moment i can only iterate over a particular hash key like this after getting the response from the api.

```
match_array = response["matches"]
match_array.each do | value |
  MatchScore.create(winner: value["score"]["winner"])
end
```

What i want is to be able to iterate over the response hash and save a record whiles passing in values from other hash keys. For example;

```
MatchScore.create(winner: value["score"]["winner"], competition_id: competition[:id])
```

Comment: Could you just use `response["competition"]["id"]`?

Comment: ahh that works. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `response["competition"]["id"]`